# Bind a dynamic object list to a repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, repeater

Good morning folks. I have been working with what should be a simple website with a repeater and a list of dynamic objects. I have my data set up with a parent object containing four list properties of four other objects.

Request (Parent)

- Event
- Flight
- Hotel
- Car

  ```
   <asp:Repeater ID="rptEvent" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                       <table class="tableStyle">
                          <tr>
                              <td colspan="4" class="headerLabel">
                                  CLIENT EVENT INFORMATION - <%# Eval("ProjectName") %>
                              </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                              <td class="regLabel row1">Company Name: (If Billable)</td>
                              <td colspan="3" class="row1">
                                  <asp:DropDownList ID="cboClientName" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="dropDownClass1" DataSource='<%# Eval("ClientName") %>' SelectedValue='<%# Eval("SelectedClientName") %>' ClientIDMode="Static" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboClientName_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
                              </td>
                          </tr>
                          [...more items...]
                      </table> 
                      <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlAdd" Visible="<%# Container.ItemIndex + 1 == tempRequest.events.Count && tempRequest.events.Count < 3 %>">
                          <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="regLabel" Text="Would you like to add another destination?&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" />
                          <asp:CheckBox ID="inptAdditionalInfo" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="inptAdditionalInfo_CheckedChanged" /><br /><br />
                      </asp:Panel>
                 </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
  ```

What happens here is the page initially loads with one object in each of the property lists and everything is fantastic and looks great. Each of the objects contain different property types. Lists of strings, individual string properties, dateTime properties, etc., and I have what I THINK is the proper syntax for binding those values to the objects. However, the issue comes in when the User checks the check box to add more items.

The page reloads before anything else happens and this creates a "re-boot" of the initial data and the data doesn't persist. I have an update method in the code behind that I thought would work correctly.

```
   protected void UpdateRequest() {

    for (int i = 0; i <= tempRequest.events.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        // Set the Event ===============================================================================
        var temp = (DropDownList)rptEvent.Items[i].FindControl("cboClientName");
        tempRequest.events[i].SelectedClientName = temp.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

It doesn't work and I am not getting persistent data. How do I properly bind the values of each repeater control to the proper item in the proper object? IE: ClientName from the second index of the repeater to the second index of the object list?

I hope I have given enough information for this question.

Answer (score 0):

After much research and digging, I discovered a few things. One, I needed to use ViewState[] to keep persistent data between clicks and refreshes. Second, the order of saving the data off to the objects was a little backwards.

I have this fixed now. Thank you for reading.